# PyQt6: AttributeError: type object 'Qt' has no attribute 'white'

Tags: python, pyqt6

PyQt6 i tried to use black color using Qt.black but it return an error 'Qt' object has no attribute 'black'

from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt

print(Qt.white)

Comment: use `Qt.GlobalColor.white`